# Linearity (or lack thereof) of the Poynting vector

Tags: electromagnetism, linear-systems, poynting-vector

Maxwell's equations are linear. If we have a solution for the electromagnetic fields $\vec{E},\vec{H}$, and another solution $\vec{E}',\vec{H}'$, then $\vec{E}+\vec{E}',\vec{H}+\vec{H}'$ is also a solution.

The Poynting vector is nonlinear. I see no mathematical reason to expect that
$$\vec{E}\times \vec{H} + \vec{E}'\times \vec{H}' = (\vec{E}+\vec{E}')\times (\vec{H}+\vec{H}')$$

But this seems ... surprising. Do the cross terms $\vec{E}\times \vec{H}'$ and $\vec{E}'\times \vec{H}$ cancel out, somehow? Or is it really true that we learn nothing about the power flow of $\vec{E}+\vec{E}',\vec{H}+\vec{H}'$ just by knowing the power flows in $\vec{E},\vec{H}$ and $\vec{E}',\vec{H}'$?

Comment: Yep. Poynting vector is nonlinear. If you comine two coherent light-beams with amplitude $E$ the resultant beam could have amplitude $2E$ and Poynting vector proportional to $4E^2$. Normally we do not see these effects in every-day optics because most of the light is incoherent, and so different beams combine as if Poynting vector was linear (i.e. $E^2$ & $E^2$ give $2E^2$).

Comment: Of course energy flow isn’t linear! That’s what interference is all about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [Young's double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)? Each of the slits is effectively a "source" for the EM field between the slits and the screen. And the pattern we see on the screen represents the power delivered by the combined sources at each point on the screen.

Now consider the possibility of introducing an optical flat in the path to one of the slits, so by changing the thickness of the flat, we can change the phase of the wave reaching that slit relative to the other. As we adjust the flat thickness, we'll see the peaks of the pattern on the screen shift their positions.

So, without knowing the phase of $\vec{E}$ from a source, we can't know how it will interfere with the $\vec{E}$ from another source.

And just knowing the power due to each source individually does not tell us how much power will be delivered to a certain surface when the two sources are combined.

Comment: Why so complicated?

Answer (score 2):

We learn something (for example, a limit on magnitude that the Poynting vector of the sum field cannot surpass), but not all details ( components of the Poynting vector for the sum field). Poynting vectors of two different fields do not determine Poynting vector of the sum field. Mathematically, products $a_1b_1, a_2b_2$ do not determine product $(a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2)$.

Equation that $(E,H)$ obeys is linear, so sum of solutions for $(E,H)$ is a solution of that equation too. Equation that $\vec{E}\times \vec{H}$ obeys is not linear, so sum of solutions for $\vec{E}\times \vec{H}$ is not, in general, a solution.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake is that you omitted the terms $ \vec{E}\times \vec{H}'$ and + $\vec{E}'\times \vec{H}$ in the left hand side.

Comment: I literally wrote that I do *not* expect that formula to be correct, due to the missing cross terms.

Comment: And there is your mistake: you should _include_ the cross terms.

Comment: Of course I should, and I knew that all along. That was *not* the question. I *expected* the cross terms had to be there, which implies that knowledge of the Poynting vectors for the E,H and E',H' solutions does not suffice to know the Poynting vector for the E+E',H+H' solution. It is this point I sought to clarify.

Comment: Those terms are there you just don't write them down. You should not add up Poynting vectors. You should add up fields and then calculate the Poynting vector.